# CakePHP: calling function in the AppController but not effect some exception

Tags: php, cakephp

Normally, in cakephp there is Auth component to help user login and there is function Auth->Allow() to make the guests users still can access to some pages like Index. But now i want that only Activated account can access almost every function of the web, but still except some normal pages like index, view etc.
I have a fucntion in Appcontroller

```
public function is_activated(){
    $userId = $this->Auth->user('id');
    $user = $this->Users->find('all', [
            'conditions' => ['id' => $userId],
            'fields' => ['id', 'email', 'activated']
        ])->first();
    $activated = $user->activated;
    if($activated !== 1){
            $this->Flash->error(__('Your account is not yet activated'));
            return $this->redirect('/users/activate');
    }
}
```

I call it in BeforeFilter along with Auth->allow() in ProjectsController:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Auth->allow(['index', 'getMyProjects']);
    $this->is_activated();
}
```

But in this way, every pages are affected and Auth->allow() not working anymore. Can anybody show me a better way for my is_activated() function, i guess that this way i redirect the web is not a good way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is isAuthorized() function:

```
public function isAuthorized($user){
    if($user->activated){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Put it in your AppController, you can also override it in your other controllers. If present, it will be automatically called.

Further reading:

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#authorization

Comment: is that function default commented?

Comment: can i just call is_activated function before any action i want to be restricted?

Comment: Please read docs first. In isAuthorized() method you can write your authorization code, and it should return true if user is authorized, or false if user is not. What I posted is just an example. You can expand it by adding more code, specific to your controller. For example, you can authorize all users to view index() action, and authorize only activated users to view() action, using conditional statements and $this->request->getParam('action'). It will affect only logged in users, so with Auth::allow() you still can manage actions available to not logged in visitors.

Comment: what if i have 3 levels, guest, un-activated member and activated one?

Comment: Guests (if by this name you are referring to not logged in visitors) are handled by Auth::allow(). Users that have logged in are handled by isAuthorized. If user not authorized, you can set an unauthorizedRedirect url in your Auth options to which they will be redirected. Please check all available options for AuthComponent: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuration-options